# Converting csv file with SED into new output format?

Tags: csv, unix, sed, command-line

I am having a csv file containing 900 rows with columns ranging from 8 to 400. Is there a way with sed where I can convert it from

```
var1, var2, var3, var4
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5
```

to

```
var1, var2, var3 \t "var4"
var1, var2, var3 \t "var4" "var5" "var6" "var7" "var8"
var1, var2, var3 \t "var4" "var5"
```

where the first 3 variables/columns are comma separated. These are then separated from the rest of the columns/variables (that are surrounded by " and space separated) with a tab.

I found out how to add quotes around the third column, but I am not sure how to do it from the third column to the rest of the columns (which numbers vary) for all the rows.

```
sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,){2})([^,]+)/\1"\3"/
```

And how to substitute the third delimiter (,) with another (\t):

```
sed 's/,/\t/3' tmp.csv
```

But I am not sure how to change the delimiters from the 4th position to space and forward for the remaining columns.

I hope that some of you, more experienced sed users, are able to help me.

Thank you!

Cheers, Birgitte

Comment: The solution: `sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/4g;s/,/ /4g;s/,/\t/3'`

Answer (score 0):

awk is good at handling column-based data.

One way to go with awk:

```
awk -F', ' -v q='"' '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(i==3){$i=$i"\t";continue}
        $i=i<3?($i","):(q $i q)
    }}7' file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, the code has no effect on the csv file (i.e. no changes)

Comment: @Biogitte it outputs on stdout. If you want to do change in place: `awk '...' file.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv file.csv`

Comment: Thanks, but the new file also seems unchanged. I got it to work with sed like: `sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/4g;s/,/ /4g;s/,/\t/3'. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/\t/3;s/,//3g;s/\S\+/"&"/4g' file
```

Replace the third `,` with a tab. Remove globally `,'s from the third onwards. Likewise, surround fields with double quotes from the fourth field onwards.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not quite what I want - the result ends up to be something like:
`var1, var2, var3 \t var4var5var6var7var8` instead of `var1, var2, var3 \t "var4" "var5" "var6" "var7" "var8"`

Comment: After playing around a bit with your code, I found the following solution: `sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/4g;s/,/ /4g;s/,/\t/3'` which works :-) 
**s/[^,]*/"&"/4g** adds quotes ("&") around the columns (specified by [^,] from the 4th column and forward (4g). **;s/,/ /4g** substitutes commas with spaces from the 4th column. **;s/,/\t/3** substitutes the 3rd comma with a tab.

Comment: @Biogitte using the sample data you provided,  your solution introduces a space following the first double quotes i.e. `[^,]` will also include spaces.

Comment: Ah, yes I can see that now! Thank you for notifying me with this